# how to sum the values which are bigger than 0?

Tags: c#

Actually i adding the values from b1, b2, b3, b4 and dividing to the numbers of B's i have (4)

```
public Media()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    double b1 = 0;
    double b2 = 0;
    double b3 = 0;
    double b4 = 0;
    double soma = 0;
    double result = 0;


    private void cmdcalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        b1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtb1.Text);
        b2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtb2.Text);
        b3 = Convert.ToDouble(txtb3.Text);
        b4 = Convert.ToDouble(txtb4.Text);

        soma = b1 + b2 + b3 + b4;
        result = soma / 4;
        lblmedia.Text = result.ToString();
    }
```

, but i need to add just the values bigger than 0 and divide to the quantity of numbers bigger than 0 i have

how i can make this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the syntax of the language. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend a much more functional approach. Though I'm not really fond of C#, here's a scratch:

```
    Double b1, b2, b3, b4, soma, count, result = 0;

// At some point you set stuff
b1 = 4;
b2 = 5;
b3 = 0;
b4 = 6;

// And at another point
IEnumerable<Double> list = (new List<Double>{b1, b2, b3, b4}).Where(x => x > 0);

soma = list.Sum();
count = list.Count();

result = soma / count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not be more generic, and allow for any number of items? (And fewer lines of code)

```
public Media()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

List<double> b = new List<double>();
double soma = 0;
double result = 0;


private void cmdcalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // txtb is an array too in this instance
    b.AddRange(txtb.Select(item => Convert.ToDouble(item.Text)));

    IEnumerable<double> relevant = b.Where(item => item > 0);
    soma = relevant.Sum();
    result = soma / relevant.Count();
    lblmedia.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Good approach, just a small note - OP wanted to divide by the number of numbers > 0, you're dividing by the total count instead.

Answer (score -1):

Read up on [conditional statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and you'll be able to do your calculations within them based on the criteria (conditions).

Comment: Not my downvote, but I guess because it's a good comment, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I guess you're right. The original post is pretty clear that he wants the code written for him rather than learn how to do it himself.

Answer (score -1):

```
int divi = 0;
double sum = 0;
b1 = Convert.ToDouble(txtb1.Text);
if (b1 > 0) { sum +=b1; divi++; }

b2 = Convert.ToDouble(txtb2.Text);
if (b2 > 0) { sum +=b2; divi++; }

b3 = Convert.ToDouble(txtb3.Text);
if (b3 > 0) { sum +=b3; divi++; }

b4 = Convert.ToDouble(txtb4.Text);
if (b4 > 0) { sum +=b4; divi++; }

if (divi > 0)
{ 
    result = sum / divi;
}
lblmedia.Text = result.ToString();
```